# Handling missing values in Stats aggregation on a nested object

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation

I have an index **test_2** with below mapping

```
{
    "mappings": {
        "properties": {
            "numberFacets": {
                "type": "nested",
                "include_in_parent": true,
                "properties": {
                    "facetName": {
                        "type": "keyword"
                    },
                    "facetValue": {
                        "type": "long"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and I have some documents added to the index

```
POST http://localhost:9200/test_2/_doc/1

{
    "numberFacets": [
        {
            "facetName": "Time1",
            "facetValue": 177
        }
    ]
}

POST http://localhost:9200/test_2/_doc/2

{
    "numberFacets": [
        {
            "facetName": "Time1",
            "facetValue": 180
        },
        {
            "facetName": "Time2",
            "facetValue": 45
        }
    ]
}

POST http://localhost:9200/test_2/_doc/3

{
    "numberFacets": [
        {
            "facetName": "Time1",
            "facetValue": 45
        },
        {
            "facetName": "Time2",
            "facetValue": 100
        }
    ]
}

POST http://localhost:9200/test_2/_doc/4

{
    "numberFacets": [
        {
            "facetName": "Time2",
            "facetValue": 3
        }
    ]
}

POST http://localhost:9200/test_2/_doc/5

{
    "numberFacets": [
        {
            "facetName": "Time2",
            "facetValue": 50
        }
    ]
}
POST http://localhost:9200/test_2/_doc/6

{
    "numberFacets": [
        {
            "facetName": "Time1",
            "facetValue": 200
        }
    ]
}
```

As you can see some of the documents have missing values.  Eg: Document 1 doesn't have a Time2 value.

Now I am trying to filter on **Time1** with min and max values as 177 and 200 respectively.

```
{
    "aggregations": {
        "TimeAggregation": {
            "aggregations": {
                "agg_number_facet": {
                    "aggregations": {
                        "facetName": {
                            "aggregations": {
                                "numberFacetValue": {
                                    "stats": {
                                        "field": "numberFacets.facetValue"
                                    }
                                }
                            },
                            "terms": {
                                "field": "numberFacets.facetName"
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "nested": {
                        "path": "numberFacets"
                    }
                }
            },
            "filter": {
                "bool": {
                    "filter": {
                        "nested": {
                            "path": "numberFacets",
                            "query": {
                                "bool": {
                                    "filter": [
                                        {
                                            "term": {
                                                "numberFacets.facetName": "Time1"
                                            }
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "range": {
                                                "numberFacets.facetValue": {
                                                    "from": "177",
                                                    "include_lower": true,
                                                    "include_upper": true,
                                                    "to": "200"
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }
                                    ]
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "size": 0
}
```

I got the aggregation result as below

```
    "aggregations": {
        "TimeAggregation": {
            "doc_count": 3,
            "agg_number_facet": {
                "doc_count": 4,
                "facetName": {
                    "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
                    "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
                    "buckets": [
                        {
                            "key": "Time1",
                            "doc_count": 3,
                            "numberFacetValue": {
                                "count": 3,
                                "min": 177.0,
                                "max": 200.0,
                                "avg": 185.66666666666666,
                                "sum": 557.0
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "key": "Time2",
                            "doc_count": 1,
                            "numberFacetValue": {
                                "count": 1,
                                "min": 45.0,
                                "max": 45.0,
                                "avg": 45.0,
                                "sum": 45.0
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

With this results i will be showing three records on the front end with the **Time1** filter selected and **Time2** filter having a  min and max value as **45**. This doesn't represent the results as we have three documents out of which 2 documents doesn't have **Time2** set. ie,  **Time2** is missing for these records. Is there a way we can get the min value of **Time2** in aggregation results as 0 if the value is missing in those documents.